# Late 2014 crashing a few times an hour, but not in safe mode. Now what?

Tags: crash

I have a late 2014 (latest version of Big Sur) I'm using as a second computer. It has a nearly fresh OS install with only a few apps installed a a few homebrew packages installed.

As the title states, the computer crashes very frequently when not in safe mode. Not sure how to further isolate the problem. Any guidance appreciated.

I ran `systemextensionsctl list` and it showed 0 extensions installed.

Also did a pram reset but that didn't help.

Thanks.

Here is one of the logs in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` called `Kernel_2022-03-10-003707_Seans-iMac.gpuRestart`

```
Thu Mar 10 00:37:07 2022

Event:               GPU Reset
Date/Time:           Thu Mar 10 00:37:07 2022
Application:         WindowServer
Path:                /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Tailspin:            /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/gpuRestart2022-03-10-003707.tailspin
GPUSubmission Trace ID: 0
OS Version:          Mac OS X Version 11.6.4 (Build 20G417)
Graphics Hardware:   AMD Radeon R9 M295X
Signature:           1

Report Data:

GPU Log Version: 2

Restart Channel: 0 GFX

---THE STATE OF THE DRIVER---

AMDRadeonX4000_AMDTongaGraphicsAccelerator state: ENABLED
 PCIe Device: [1:0:0], DID=0x6938, RID=0x0, SSID=0x13a
 TotalVideoRAMBytes: 0x0000000100000000 (4294967296)
Uptime 0:08:13.332274

[00] Channel: GFX (HW [00]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:07:51.582283
  CompletedTS = 0x0000d791, SubmittedTS = 0x0000d7a7
  Sent to HW: TS = 0x0000d792 (HW TS = 0x0000d798, WPTR = 0x1cd80) at 0:07:51.582797
  ScheduledTS = 0x0000d796, enqueued at 0:07:56.586106
   Wait for Channel 5, TS 0x6e3c
  FirstPendingCB: Process ID = 133, Name = WindowServer; SubmitContext = Metal (0xffffff936c099000)
      GPUAddress = 0x0000000416db0000, Size = 0x000002e0, VMID = 2
      ContentValidation = PASS
      Execution point 0x2e0
      Buffer range 0x249 .. 0x2df:
       c0206900  00000191  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
       00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
       00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
       00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
       00000000  00000000  c0012800  80000002  80000000  c0012800  80000000  80000000 
       c0002a00  00000000  c0002f00  00000000  c0017900  10000242  00000000  c0026900 
       0000008e  0000000f  0000000f  c0026900  00000003  00000000  00000080  c0036900 
       00000201  00301101  00cc0010  00000010  c0016900  00000207  00000000  c0016900 
       000002f8  00000000  c0016900  000001b1  00000000  c0046900  000001b3  00000002 
       00000002  0000246a  00000001  c0016900  000001b8  01000000  c0036900  000001c3 
       00000004  00000000  00000004  c0057600  00000007  003fffff  0400107b  00000000 
       002c02c1  0000000c  c0067600  00000046  003fffff  00000017  04000290  00000000 
       002c02c1  0000000c  c0067600  0000000c  04e70000  00000004  00060000  00000004 
       04e70110  00000004  c0047600  0000004c  00000000  00000000  04e70120  00000004 
       c0027600  0000004c  00000000  00000000  c0017900  10000242  00000004  c0016900 
       100002aa  201c003f  c0002f00  00000001  c0012d00  00000006  00000002  c0004600 
       00000410  c0004200  00000000  c0004600  00000016  c0034300  82844000  ffffffff 
       00000000  00000004  c00b1000  00000000  3f800000  c0066900  0000013f  45480000 
       45480000  c4e10000  44e10000  3f800000  00000000  c0026900  000000c6 

[01] Channel: Compute0 (HW [01]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:07:51.582283
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000

[02] Channel: Compute1 (HW [02]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:07:51.582283
  CompletedTS = 0x000000a4, SubmittedTS = 0x000000a4

[03] Channel: Compute2 (HW [03]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:07:51.582283
  CompletedTS = 0x00000004, SubmittedTS = 0x00000004

[05] Channel: sDMA0 (HW [05]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:07:51.582283
  CompletedTS = 0x00006e39, SubmittedTS = 0x00006e47
  ScheduledTS = 0x00006e3a, enqueued at 0:07:56.586370
   Wait for Channel 0, TS 0xd794

[06] Channel: sDMA1 (HW [06]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000d37, SubmittedTS = 0x00000d37

[07] Channel: UVD (HW [07]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000

[08] Channel: VCE (HW [08]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000

[09] Channel: VCELLQ (HW [09]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000

[10] Channel: SAMU RBI (HW [10]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000

[11] Channel: SAMU GPCOM (HW [11]); Priority 2; last reset at 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000

[18] Channel: VMPT (HW [06]); Priority 0; last reset at 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x0000904b, SubmittedTS = 0x0000904b

Pipe 0: Active, submitted = 3833, performed = 3831
 STAT e20 MODE 0 SLAV 2 WSAA 1 WSAAPS 1 DISP 0 PWR 2 MODE 80001002 HA 2560 VA 2880 HS 6400 VS 3600 PCLK 483250  PD 0 DPCH 0 DPSM 0 LHPT 0 STAT e7 PWR 0 0 V Counter diff d8 10a07 0 SMU 1

Pipe 1: Not active, submitted = 0, performed = 0
 STAT 620 MODE 0 SLAV 0 WSAA 0 WSAAPS 0 DISP 0 PWR 2 MODE a00 HA 2560 VA 2880 HS 5120 VS 2880 PCLK 483250  PD 0 DPCH 0 DPSM 0 LHPT 0 STAT e7 PWR 0 0 V Counter diff ba 10a07 0 SMU 1

Pipe 2: Not active, submitted = 0, performed = 0
 STAT 600 MODE 4 SLAV 0 WSAA 0 WSAAPS 0 DISP 0 PWR 2  PD 0 DPCH 0 DPSM 0 LHPT 0 STAT e7 PWR 0 0 V Counter diff 0 10007 0 SMU 1

Pipe 3: Not active, submitted = 0, performed = 0
 STAT 600 MODE 4 SLAV 0 WSAA 1 WSAAPS 1 DISP 0 PWR 2  PD 0 DPCH 0 DPSM 0 LHPT 0 STAT e7 PWR 0 0 V Counter diff 0 10007 0 SMU 1
----------------------------------------
--- DRIVER STATE TRACE---               
DeviceID                                : [1:0:0]
----------------------                  
u64AllAccel                             : 0x0000000000003fff
----------------------                  
accelStart_entry                        : 1
accelStarted                            : 1
accelStart_exit                         : 1
configureDevice_entry                   : 1
deviceConfigured                        : 1
configureDevice_exit                    : 1
initLinkToPeer                          : 1
createHWHandler                         : 1
createHWInterface                       : 1
accelPowerUpHW_entry                    : 1
accelPowerUpHW                          : 1
accelPowerUpHW_exit                     : 1
bltMgrInitialized                       : 1
atomicBltMgrInitialized                 : 1
----------------------                  
u64AllHW                                : 0x0000000000ff7fff
----------------------                  
hardwareInit_entry                      : 1
hardwareInit                            : 1
hardwareInit_exit                       : 1
initExternalInterfaces                  : 1
hwRegistersInitialized                  : 1
mapDoorbellMemory                       : 1
setupCail                               : 1
initCail                                : 1
setupInitHWCapabilities                 : 1
allocateHWEngines                       : 1
initializeHWEngines                     : 1
powerUpHWEngines                        : 1
startHWEngines                          : 1
initHWInfo                              : 1
hardwarePowerUp_entry                   : 1
hardwarePowerUp                         : 1
hardwarePowerUp_exit                    : 1
initializeTtl                           : 0
hwMemoryInitialized                     : 1
hwGartInitialized                       : 1
hwVmmInitialized                        : 1
initHWDisplay                           : 1
setVirtualSpace                         : 1
initializeHWRegisters                   : 1
----------------------------------------

---THE STATE OF THE GPU---
GPU is connected to PCIe bus and Register access is correct.
 timeSinceLastPowerUp = 0:08:00.674611

[00] HWChannel: GFX, Priority 2, last reset 0:07:51.582282
  CompletedTS = 0x0000d797, SubmittedTS = 0x0000d79b
  PendingTS = 0xd798, sent at 0:07:51.582797, AccelChannel: 0, TS = 0xd792
  Ring: ENABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000100020000, Size = 0x20000, ReadPtr = 0x0001cf00, WritePtr = 0x0001cf00

[01] HWChannel: Compute0, Priority 2, last reset 0:07:51.582283
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000
  Ring: ENABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x00000001000c0000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000

[02] HWChannel: Compute1, Priority 2, last reset 0:07:51.582283
  CompletedTS = 0x000000a4, SubmittedTS = 0x000000a4
  Ring: ENABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000100100000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000

[03] HWChannel: Compute2, Priority 2, last reset 0:07:51.582283
  CompletedTS = 0x00000004, SubmittedTS = 0x00000004
  Ring: ENABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000100140000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000

[04] HWChannel: KIQ, Priority 2, last reset 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x0000000b, SubmittedTS = 0x0000000b
  Ring: ENABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000100180000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00000080, WritePtr = 0x00000080

[05] HWChannel: sDMA0, Priority 2, last reset 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00006e39, SubmittedTS = 0x00006e39
  Ring: ENABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x00000001001a0000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00000e40, WritePtr = 0x00000e40
    Command Ring Snapshot:
    0x0dc0 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0dc8 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0dd0 : 00000000  00000000  00020004  005d0aa0  00000004  00000008  00000000  00000000 
    0x0dd8 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0de0 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0de8 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0df0 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000005  00000140  00000001  00006e38  00000006 
    0x0df8 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    --- Frame Boundary ---
    0x0e00 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e08 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e10 : 00000000  00000000  00020004  005d0ac0  00000004  00000008  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e18 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e20 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e28 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e30 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000005  00000140  00000001  00006e39  00000006 
    0x0e38 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    --- Frame Boundary ---
    0x0e40 :>00000000< 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e48 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e50 : 00000000  00000000  00020004  005ccde0  00000004  00000008  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e58 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e60 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e68 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x0e70 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000005  00000140  00000001  00006c3a  00000006 
    0x0e78 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 

[06] HWChannel: sDMA1, Priority 2, last reset 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00009d82, SubmittedTS = 0x00009d82
  Ring: ENABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x00000001001e0000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00006080, WritePtr = 0x00006080
    Command Ring Snapshot:
    0x6000 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6008 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6010 : 00000000  00000000  00070004  018800a0  00000004  00000008  00000000  00000000 
    0x6018 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6020 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6028 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6030 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000005  00000180  00000001  00009d81  00000006 
    0x6038 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    --- Frame Boundary ---
    0x6040 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6048 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6050 : 00000000  00000000  00070004  018800c0  00000004  00000008  00000000  00000000 
    0x6058 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6060 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6068 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6070 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000005  00000180  00000001  00009d82  00000006 
    0x6078 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    --- Frame Boundary ---
    0x6080 :>00000000< 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6088 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x6090 : 00000000  00000000  80000004  00923560  00000001  0000000a  00000000  00000000 
    0x6098 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x60a0 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x60a8 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 
    0x60b0 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000005  00000180  00000001  00009b83  00000006 
    0x60b8 : 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 

[07] HWChannel: UVD, Priority 2, last reset 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000
  Ring: DISABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000100220000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000

[08] HWChannel: VCE, Priority 2, last reset 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000
  Ring: DISABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000100240000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000

[09] HWChannel: VCELLQ, Priority 2, last reset 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000
  Ring: DISABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000100260000, Size = 0x8000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000

[10] HWChannel: SAMU RBI, Priority 2, last reset 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000
  Ring: DISABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000100280000, Size = 0x07f8, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000

[11] HWChannel: SAMU GPCOM, Priority 2, last reset 0:00:00.000000
  CompletedTS = 0x00000000, SubmittedTS = 0x00000000
  Ring: DISABLED
    GPUAddress = 0x00000001002a0000, Size = 0x0800, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000

Graphic and Compute(GC):
  Graphic Ring: GPUAddress = 0x0000000100020000, Size = 0x00020000, ReadPtr = 0x0001cf00, WritePtr = 0x0001cf00
  Compute(1,0,0) Queue: GPUAddress = 0x00000001000c0000, Size = 0x00008000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000
    IB: GPUAddress = 0x0000000000000000, ConsumedSize = 0x00000000, RemainSize=0x00000000 [COMPLETED]
  Compute(1,1,0) Queue: GPUAddress = 0x0000000100100000, Size = 0x00008000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000
    IB: GPUAddress = 0x0000000000000000, ConsumedSize = 0x00000000, RemainSize=0x00000000 [COMPLETED]
  Compute(1,2,0) Queue: GPUAddress = 0x0000000100140000, Size = 0x00008000, ReadPtr = 0x00000000, WritePtr = 0x00000000
    IB: GPUAddress = 0x0000000000000000, ConsumedSize = 0x00000000, RemainSize=0x00000000 [COMPLETED]
  Compute(1,3,0) Kiq: GPUAddress = 0x0000000100180000, Size = 0x00008000, ReadPtr = 0x00000080, WritePtr = 0x00000080
    IB: GPUAddress = 0x0000000000000000, ConsumedSize = 0x00000000, RemainSize=0x00000000 [COMPLETED]
  GC Pipeline Status:
    Command Processor(CP): CPFetchers= BUSY CPGraphics= BUSY CPCompute= IDLE
      PreFetchParser(PFP): ACTIVE
        PFP Last Processed Commands: 
          0xffff1000
          0xffff1000
          0xffff1000
          0xffff1000
          0xffff1000
      MicroEngineGraphic(ME): ACTIVE
        ME Last Processed Commands: 
          0xc0044700
          0xc0044700
          0xc0044700
          0xc0044000
          0xc0044700
      MicroEngineCompute0(MEC0): ACTIVE
      MicroEngineCompute1(MEC1): HALT
    Graphic Engine Setup: IDLE
    Unified Shader Processor and Input: IDLE
    Texture Pipe: IDLE
    Render Backend: IDLE

SDMA0: ACTIVE and IDLE
  MicroEngine: ACTIVE
  Ring: GPUAddress = 0x0000000001001a00, Size = 0x00008000, ReadPtr = 0x00000e40, WritePtr = 0x00000e40
    IB: [ENABLE] GPUAddress = 0x00000004005d0ac0, ConsumedSize = 0x00000020, RemainSize=0x00000000

SDMA1: ACTIVE and IDLE
  MicroEngine: ACTIVE
  Ring: GPUAddress = 0x0000000001001e00, Size = 0x00008000, ReadPtr = 0x00006080 WritePtr = 0x00006080
    IB: [ENABLE] GPUAddress = 0x00000004018800c0, ConsumedSize = 0x00000020, RemainSize=0x00000000

UVD0: Disabled

VCE: Disabled

SAMU: Disabled

VM Protection Fault:
  System Domain: YES
    GPUAddress = 0x0000000400022000, VMID = 0
    Failing Protection = RANGE, 
    MC Client: TC8
    Page table: 0x0000000400021000 .. 0x0000000400022000
Requested range (start 0x400021000, size 0x1001) is invalid.
  Virtual Domain: YES
    GPUAddress = 0x000000040822c000, VMID = 2
    Failing Protection = VALID, READ, 
    MC Client: SDM0
    Page table: 0x000000040822b000 .. 0x000000040822c000
[0000000000000000] [0000000065aaa0f1] 
------------------------
: ** GPU Debug Info Start **
: 0x00006938 : 0x000000fd : 0x00000001 : 0x00000018 : 0x00009000 : 0x00000001 : 0x00000001 : 0x00006938 
: 0x00000001 : 0x00000015 : 0x00000000 : 0x00000001 : 0x00000047 

<snip>

System Profile:
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 26.1
Boot Volume File System Type: apfs
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x859B, 0x43543130323436344246313630422E433136
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x859B, 0x43543130323436344246313630422E433136
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x859B, 0x43543130323436344246313630422E433136
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x859B, 0x43543130323436344246313630422E433136
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM1024F, 1 TB
Model: iMac15,1, BootROM 432.60.3.0.0, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 4 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 2.23f11
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonR9M295XItem, AMD Radeon R9 M295X, spdisplays_pcie_device, 4 GB
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x142), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1680.9)
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.5d7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
```

Comment: Please add links to a few of your crash reports.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not save the kernel panic message that pops up after the machine reboots. But it is definitely the WindowServer component causing the problem. It's timing out, according to the message. This indicates some kind of problem with the graphics. I've since discovered the machine does not crash when running at the default screen resolution. All the crashes have happened at the highest screen resolution. I'm not sure if this indicates a hardware or software problem. Maybe high resolution is causing gpu to heat up?

Answer (score 0):

[Apple suggests the following](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201262) -

> If updating your software doesn't help, try any of these solutions:
>
> - Test your login items.
> - To find out whether software in your user account is causing the issue, set up a new user account, then log in to it and try to reproduce the issue in that account.
> - Unplug all accessories from your Mac, including printers, drives, USB hubs and other non-essential devices. There could be an issue with one or more of those devices or their cables.
> - Reinstall macOS.